# Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> **Manifest merger failed** : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [**com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1**] E:\WorkSpace\AndStudio\Test1\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage

Answer (score 2):

To use that support library version your min SDK needs to be at least 14.

Also you might want to actually ask a question rather than just pasting an error